# Are Great Old Ones/Imperium (Dark Tower) 'Higher Random' or 'Higher Purpose'?

Tags: the-dark-tower

So, Great Old Ones, 'For their own decadent entertainment, they created doorways that led from their world to other wheres and whens on every level of the Tower.'

But if Great Old Ones are merely mortals, (which means they're Short-Timers instead of Long-Timers or All-Timers), then they can't have access to whole Tower because

> [Short-Timers and Long-Timers live in overlapping spheres of existence -on connected floors of the same building if you like - ruled by the Random and the Purpose. Above these floors, inaccessible to us but very much a part of the same tower of existence, live other beings. Some of them are marvelous and wonderful; others are hideous beyond out ability to comprehend, let alone yours. These beings might be called the Higher Purpose and the Higher Random. -Insomnia]

Yes, there are 'elevators' within Dark Tower but

> [Clotho: [As I was saying, there are elevators, but Short-Timers are not allowed to use them under ordinary circumstances. - Insomnia]

So, I think its pretty much impossible for Great Old Ones to have access to every level of the Tower (using elevators) if they aren't Higher Random/Purpose, let alone build doorways (which probably means equal to 'build' said 'elevators') to do that.

So, could it be that Great Old Ones/Old People are Higher Purpose or Higher Random themselves?

Comment: Isn't Clotho trying to talk about the levels of existence that the character in Insomnia is going through, not the Dark Tower specifically?  That book never had more than a tangent to the main series, other than trying to introduce the concept of the Crimson King.

Comment: Well it looks like talking about 'floors' though. But maybe not, just as you said, 'not Dark Tower specifically', as even Roland is able to climb to top of the Tower to my knowledge. (i haven't read the books myself though, so sorry for any wrong assumptions I made)

Comment: That is kinda related, but even "Dark Tower" had serious problems with self-consistency. Old Ones didn't need any "allowance" power wasn't inherent to them, but no-one stopped them in getting it. It was no "ordinary circumstance".